# mysql stored procedure does not find table due to Case

Tags: mysql

I'm currently moving my project to production and found an odd situation. The database was (unfortunately) created with object names in lowercase. Now, I'm acting on table all over my 100+ stored procedures/functions, not always keeping in mind the fact that I should use lowercase for table names.

I made a simple test:

```
select * from mytable ;
```

yields all the records in the table, whereas:

```
select * from Mytable ;
```

returns a "table does not exist" error.

Is there any solution someone could suggest besides going one by one through each and every stored procedure/function and correct the case of the table names?

Thanking in advance for any life-saving suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to software development, where the deploy to production never goes quite the way you hope it will.

Comment: Well my dear friend, I have quite some experience with other DBMSs (ORACLE, MS-SQL) and in no case I had to care about case of table names.

Comment: yeah me neither. So I make everything lowercase. Works like a charm in either environment.

Comment: that's like saying you always drive an automatic, so in no case have you had to worry about shifting gears.  You changed something in the code you deployed to prod and the code you deployed to dev, and it mattered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation on cases in identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data
>   directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one
>   file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on
>   the storage engine). Triggers also correspond to files. Consequently,
>   the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part
>   in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names.

I would probably take the time to make everything lower case because it will save you headaches further down the line. If you have a client with a decent editor like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) then you can do these replaces with a quick find and replace.

EDIT:

According to the documentation, you can try setting the `lower_case_table_names` system variable to 1, which will:

> Table names are stored in lowercase on disk and name comparisons are
>   not case sensitive. MySQL converts all table names to lowercase on
>   storage and lookup. This behavior also applies to database names and
>   table aliases.

This might solve your problem if all of the table had been created with lowercase on disk.

Comment: Hummmm. I had other hopes... As mentioned, there are 100+ stored procedures/functions.

Comment: I updated my answer with more information from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @gr1zzlybe4r for your comments. From what I understand, it all comes down to how the OS works (case sensitivity on filenames YES/NO). Even if I could request from MySQL to look for a table regardless of the case, it might result into a lot of I/Os vis-à-vis the disk. I think that the best (though highly painful) will be to walk through all the code and make sure that table names are in lowercase.